# MS Reporting Services stacked bar chart with custom series fill color shows wrong legend colors

Tags: reporting-services, colors, legend, stacked-bar-chart

I have a SSRS stacked bar chart with Regions (on the x axis) as category and Countries as a Serie. I have a property from the Dataset called "Fields!ReportColor.Value" which I used in the formula to set the Series fill color. This formula is working fine for the color of the stacked bars, but it seems not working to set the color of the corresponding legends: in particular the right color is applied only to the legend corresponding to the first serie (the first country), all the subsequent values of the series (the other countries) are wrong.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wpvB.png)
[results:] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT0Qu.png)

As a form of debugging I used a conditional expression that returns the Fields!ReportColor.Value if this is not null and the color "Red" if this value is null: what I noticed is that while for the bars the right color is still applied, for the legends that are not corresponding to the first country the color "Red" is applied; it seems that the formula is receiving the dataset values only for the first item, but only when it is used to format the Legend color. Is there anything that I am missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce the problem but it works as expected for me.

Here's the steps I took.

Created some test data. This is the dataset query

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Continent varchar(50), Country varchar(50), x int, Colour varchar(30))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('West Europe', 'UK', 10, '#335070'),
('West Europe', 'France', 8, '#FF0000'),
('West Europe', 'Germany', 9, '#00FF00'),
('West Europe', 'Italy', 2, '#0000FF'),
('West Europe', 'Spain', 6, '#DDDDDD'),
('North America', 'USA', 7, '#AABBCC'),
('North America', 'Canada', 1, '#00CCDD'),
('East Europe', 'Poland', 3, '#523456'),
('East Europe', 'Romainia', 9, '#998877')

SELECT * FROM @t
```

Added a stacked column chart, added a category group for 'Continent' and a Series Group for 'Country'. Set the values to 'x'

I then set the data labels to be 'country' so I could check the results.

The design looked like this.

[image]

I then set the Series Property Fill Color property to `Fields!Colour.Value`.

The final output looks like this...

[image]

As you can see the colours match both the legend and columns.

Comment: Hi Alan, many thanks for your detailed reply! Very useful. The problem, at least from further testing I did on my side, is related to the aggregation function: if I use Sum (as in your example) everything seems working fine, but if I replace the Sum with a Count (or CountDIstinct), the legends colors become messed up (plus zeros appear on my bars); does this happen to your report too?

Comment: It does, I just checked and it shows the same issue when count or count distinct is used. I guess this is a bug in SSRS, maybe worth reporting it. I haven't seen your based data but maybe you could calculate the counts you need in your dataset query, then SUM() will just sum the single value (as in my example)?

Comment: I will implement the workaround that you were suggesting and will use the SUM function instead to achieve the same result. Thanks again for your help and support.